# ¿Hay algún sustantivo para el adjetivo "adecuado"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Existen varias terminaciones para adjetivos "abstractos" en español. Pensé en estos ejemplos:

> Apto: apti**tud**
>
> bueno: bon**dad**
>
> rico: riqu**eza**
>
> avaro: avar**icia**
>
> sensato: sensa**tez**

En inglés también se puede ver una terminación que puede usarse para crear (al menos algunos) sustantivos abstractos: [ness](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ness).

> added to adjectives to form nouns that refer to a quality or a condition

Así por ejemplo, el adjetivo [*adequate*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adequateness) tendría su equivalente como sustantivo *adequate**ness***

Tomemos una frase como plantilla:

> **adjetivo: exacto**
>
> El nivel de exactitud será evaluado por expertos.
>
> **adjetivo: adecuado**
>
> El nivel de (?) será evaluado por expertos.

¿Hay algún sustantivo abstracto que se pueda formar a partir de la palabra "adecuado" y que denote el estado o condición de "ser adecuado"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tu lista de sufijos ***-ud***, ***-ad***, ***-icia*** y ***-ez(a)***, podemos añadir también ***-ción***, ya que con la misma raíz que **adecuar**, tenemos **[adecuación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0i8jUOQ)**, que el DLE define como:

> 1. f. Acción y efecto de adecuar.

Otras palabras forman sustantivos abstractos con dicho sufijo:

- Moderar → Moderación
- Organizar → Organización
- Deducir → Deducción

En esta página de la Wikipedia sobre el [sustantivo abstracto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sustantivo_abstracto) hablan de ciertos sufijos y reglas que permiten la creación de sustantivos abstractos, y hacen referencia a una gramática. Lamentablemente, no he encontrado la referencia correspondiente de la RAE.

Comment: Gracias Alicia. Yo tenía en mi mente "adecuación" como el _proceso_ de adecuar: "La adecuación de esta oficina nos llevará semanas". Pero viendo que el significado que referencias dice "Acción y **efecto** de adecuar", es claro que también es util para describir el estado o la cualidad de ser adecuado.

Answer (score 1):

Yo llevo toda la vida utilizando **adecuidad**, y me acabo de dar cuenta de que no viene en el diccionario.

No obstante, sí que viene [-idad](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BotFPGe) como sufijo para formarla:

> 1. suf. Significa 'cualidad' en sustantivos abstractos derivados de adjetivos. [...] Si el adjetivo es de más de dos sílabas, toma, en general, la forma **-idad**. *Barbaridad, afectuosidad, efectividad*.

Así que quizá **adecuidad** es correcto.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16086)

Answer (score 1):

Alentado por @aparente001, vengo a hacer mi humilde aporte.

Muchos hablantes tenemos la misma impresión que expresó Mauricio en un comentario: *Yo tenía en mi mente "adecuación" como el proceso de adecuar.*

La realidad es que el sustantivo "adecuación" remite mucho más directamente al "proceso de adecuar" que a la "calidad/condición de adecuado".

Creo que, a menos que recurramos a un sinónimo como "conveniencia", un modo de desambiguar el término de modo que signifique "calidad/condición de adecuado" consiste en utilizar algún sustantivo antes de adecuación, como "**nivel** de adecuación" o "**grado** de adecuación". Estos sustantivos nos llevarán más fácilmente a pensar en cuán adecuado es algo (más que en su posibilidad de adecuarse).

Answer (score 0):

**La suficiencia.**

Esta palabra la aprendí a usar en el contexto de la educación especial, donde hay una colaboración entre padres y maestros para hacer un Plan -- una especie de contrato -- que describe cuáles apoyos se le van a dar al niño en la escuela, y qué son las metas académicas que se consideran alcanzables en el plazo un año.

Cuando los padres no quedan conformes con el plan, pueden levantar una queja de "suficiencia," lo cual quiere decir que los padres consideran que el plan que adoptó la escuela no es *adecuado*.

Comment: @aparente001 Creo que te estás dejando llevar por el uso del inglés "adequate", que muchas veces significa "suficiente". En español ese significado es raro o inexistente, ya que lo habitual es que "adecuado" signifique "conveniente" o "apropiado".

Comment: @Gustavson - Count yourself lucky that you don't have to deal with U.S. Special Education law (IDEA) and its regulations, which are rife with the word "appropriate."  In those legal discussions, *appropriate = sufficient*.  Really, this is the only context in English where I've ever needed a noun related to either *appropriate* or *sufficient*; in Spanish I've never needed it.  Can you give me a couple of example contexts in Spanish where a noun for *adecuado* would be needed? // If I think in terms of *conveniente* as you suggested, then my noun could be *conveniencia*, I suppose.

Comment: @aparente001 To be frank, I (as well as many other speakers) tend to use "adecuación" for the action of adjusting or adapting something rather than for the result, e.g. *Es necesaria la adecuación de las medidas a los nuevos tiempos que corren.* I find it hard to find a good and idiomatic example where "adecuación" means the state of being "adecuado".

Comment: @Gustavson - That's interesting.  In your example, does *adecuación* mean something like *adjustment* or *adaptation*?

Comment: @aparente001 Exactly.

Comment: @Gustavson - Thanks.  Hmm.  The sample sentence was "El nivel de (?) será evaluado por expertos."  Seems to be a different meaning.

Comment: @aparente001 Oh, yes, I was thinking of "adecuación" in other contexts (*adecuación a algo*). In that sentence, "adecuación" is closer to "suitability", as I see it.

Comment: @Gustavson - I like *suitability*.  In some fields *appropriateness* is used.  OP wants a word in Spanish.  What's your recommendation?

Comment: @aparente001 I'd use "grado de adecuación". "adecuación" sounds very much like "adaptation", while "grado de adecuación" more readily refers to the quality of being "adecuado".

Comment: @Gustavson - OP's model sentence was *El nivel de (?) será evaluado por expertos.*  Applying your idea, I get *El nivel de adecuación [El grado de adecuación] será evaluado por expertos.*  Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Llego unos años tarde pero hace unas horas me encontré con este mismo problema.
A mi me parece que en lugar de *adecuacion* para este contexto, se puede usar *idoneidad*.

Especialmente porque no creo que las personas que esten leyendo mi trabajo se tomen el tiempo de buscar *adecuación* en el diccionario para corroborar si la utilizacion de la palabra es incorrecta.

Comment: Creo que todos estaremos de acuerdo en que "idoniedad" es el sustantivo de " idóneo", no de "adecuado